# how to put notification after some time

Tags: android, timer, notifications

Hi I'd like to put notify to user to execute the application when application on background after 5 minutes.
So, I use onWindowFocusChanged to check my app is background or not. Please help me what should I do.This is my code. Please answer me with full code.
And I'd like to notify them with popup menu.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
.............//import is too long
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.myapp.R;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button btnA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btngetA);
             btnA.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intentA = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gotoAActivity.class);

                startActivity(intentA);

            }
        });
        @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                new CountDownTimer(1000, 1) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                //timer finished

                    }

                }.start();

            }
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        }
```

this is notification. but I don't know where this codes should added..

```
 public static void createService(Context context, CharSequence tickerMessage, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, int icon, int id, Intent intent, long[] pattern, Boolean autoCancel) {
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification n;
        title="notice";
        message="execute your app!!";

        int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


        if (apiLevel >= 11) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setTicker(tickerMessage)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(p)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


            if (pattern.length > 0) {
                builder.setVibrate(pattern);
                }

            if (autoCancel != null) {
                builder.setAutoCancel(autoCancel);
            }

            if (apiLevel >= 17) {
                // Android 4.2+
                n = builder.build();
            }

            else {
                // Android 3.x
                n = builder.getNotification();
            }
        }
        else {
            // Android 2.2+
            n = new Notification(icon, tickerMessage, System.currentTimeMillis());
            // Data
            n.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, p);
        }

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(id, n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send the notification in `onFinish()` method but to be honest this code doesn't work at all. If your activity is in background can be killed by OS at anytime. What you could do is to set an alarm of 5 minutes in the `onStop()` callback of your activity and delete it in the `onStart()` callback. In this way if the activity is not started after 5 minutes you can do some work depending on what you want to do when the timer expires.